# rest client request with same param and multiple values

Tags: rest, jersey, jersey-client

I'm using Jersey 1.x rest client.
I need to do a GET request passing a param multiple times.
Using

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.queryParams(MultivaluedMap<String, String> params)
```

I can achieve what I want. But.

the generated url is something like

```
http://blablabla?foo=value1&foo=value2&foo=value3
```

is there a way to tell jersey I want to set the parameters in this way?

```
http://blablabla?foo[0]=value1&foo[1]=value2&foo[2]=value3
```